# Move active directory user based on Get-ADuser Office attribute

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I've been having an issue with moving user accounts using PowerShell. I want to move specific users accounts from OU to OU based on what they have as an `Office` attribute.

The script is:

```
$prague = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties * | Select-Object -Property Office,SamAccountName | where -Property Office -eq "prague"

Move-ADObject -Identity $prague -TargetPath "OU=LAB,DC=test,DC=cz"
```

Powershell returns:

```
Move-ADObject : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADObject' required by parameter 'Identity'. Specified method is not supported. 
   At line:6 char:25 
   + Move-ADObject -Identity $prague -TargetPath "OU=LAB,DC=test... 
   + ~~~~~~~ 
   + CategoryInfo : InvalidArgument: (:) [Move-ADObject], ParameterBindingException 
   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.MoveADObject
```

Is it possible to run `Move-ADObject` cmdlet based on the `Get-ADUser` with plenty of parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Move-Object`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ee617248.aspx) is expecting to move *one* object. You are cramming several into it via the array `$prague`. You need to use the pipeline or a loop to address this.

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {Office -eq "prague"} -Properties Office | 
    Move-ADObject  -TargetPath "OU=LAB,DC=test,DC=cz"
```

Also don't use `-Properies *` when you only need `-Properies Office`. Else you are creating a potential performance issue by pulling *all* properties, including non cached ones, into your session. We simplified this further by only querying for users of the appropriate office instead of post processing with `Where`

Comment: @Jan You are welcome. Consider marking an answer as accepted (using the checkmark beside it) if it solved your problem.